# <div> class button click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to use a userscript to click a button. According to inspect element, the button looks like:

`<div class="q-w-btn cl"></div>`

Conveniently, the web developer neglected to put an id in there, so I was not able to select it by the id and then use the click function (are they called functions in JavaScript? I'm not an expert in the language).

I have tried many, many, many different ways, and all of them have successfully failed to click the button.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks for reading about my problems.

Comment: Just to be clear, you are trying to have a function click the button above automatically? Can you show some of your attempts to do this? please refer to [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: If you can get the element, the code is `document.getElementById("ELEMENT-ID").click();`

Comment: Thanks Daniel William, but I have searched through all of the website code, and found nothing about the class'es ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get elements by class name as well in java Script like below

```
document.getElementsByClassName("q-w-btn");
```

but notice that this function will return all elements in the document having the specified class name in the form of an array. As a result if your document has only one element having this class then you need to get the first element like below.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("q-w-btn")[0];
```

And yes in java script it is called functions you can see the conventions in here http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `document.getElementsByClassName('q-w-btn')` and bind click event on it, something like -

```js
var button = document.getElementsByClassName('q-w-btn')[0];
button.addEventListener('click', function () {
  alert('here');
});
```

```html
<div class="q-w-btn">Click me</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code (Insert script before </body>):

```
var btn = document.querySelector('.q-w-btn.cl');
if (btn) {
    btn.addEventListener('click', onButtonClick);
}

function onButtonClick(evt) {
    console.log('the click event is trigger');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This (courtesy of Ramin) worked for me:

```
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("q-w-btn")[0]; btn.click();
```

Thanks to everyone who helped me learn and come to this solution.